# Use widget to add dynamic text inside the short description tab based on text attribut of product?

Tags: product-attribute, widget

I'm looking to have dynamic text that changes based on the store view and the product for seo reason. Below i've used a simple exemple of a dynamic country name :

1 - On the attribut configuration page :

- Create text attribut called "seo-word-country".

[image: side attribut]

2 - On the product configuration page :

- On store-view "Belgium", i add the word "Belgium" in the attribut text field.
- On store-view "Germany" this would be "Germany"...etc

[image: side product]

- In the short description i add the following text : This product can be shipped to your country "**widget-seo-word-country**" !.

[image: side description]

3 - On the front-end product page :

- The client and Google crawlers sees the following text on the belgium site : this product can be shipped to your country **Belgium** !

[image: side frontend]

The idear is to have only one default text in short and long description tab which changes on the front-end based on the store-view and the product page.

Big thanks in advance for your help.

Regards,
Marc

Answer (score 0):

Here alternative solution for this

```
  Add desciption in admin like below format
```

> "This clamp has an exterior size **{}** for clamping on the tube"

`{}` will replace in frontend.

```
 //Get product desciption in frontend 
  $description =  $_product->getDescription();


  //Get product attribute in frontend
  $size_clamp = $_product->getResource()->getAttribute('size_clamp')->getFrontend()->getValue($_product);
  // Assume it will retrun 27mm

  $updatedDesciption = str_replace('{}', $size_clamp, $description);
  echo  $updatedDesciption
// output   This clamp has an exterior size 27mm for clamping on the tube
```

Comment: Hi mp raj, thank you for your return. That is a great solution, it's like a variable ? Can just echo the "size-clamp" attribut and then in the text have {size-clamp} ? Or do i need to echo the entire text ?

Comment: "size-clamp" will replace the {} then echo the description text.